90/180 day rule with student resident permit, how strict it is applied
I have a student residence permit valid for another 2 years from Germany, I am from Turkey, and my sister lives in Hungary. I visit her whenever I wish with a train and I never had a problem so far, I usually spend my summers with her. I recently learn about this 90/180 days rule applied even for residence permit residents. But the problem is I never had a passport control in trains (I use trains always to travel), and I do not work there or anything; we basically aim to spend quality family time.
By the rule, I might have 6 days left and we had a family gathering planned. This rarely happens once in a year. Should I take this so serious and leave, or stay for 10 days (4 days will be over 90 days period) and do not bother? I am pretty strict with rules and regulations, so I wanna know if bilateral agreement can be applied in my case. Do I need to go police or something to justify where I am everytime I visit my sister? I will leave directly after my family leaves. Would I get banned or penalty for this incase it would become a deal?

Do you mean to say that you study in Germany, but you spent 84/180 days in Hungary?

Definitely do not try to go to the police and ask about any of this!

It is summer break, I am done with my all exams and projects. Managed them early. Some of my projects, I was able to complete online, so I used that option

The rule is phrased that way because the creation of the Schengen area created a conundrum: You cannot expect all third-country residents to apply for a short-stay Schengen visa every time they cross an internal border, this would be extremely costly and serve no purpose since there is no border checks anymore. But you cannot formally allow all residence permit holders to reside everywhere in the Schengen area, this would contradict the notion that residence permit are still a national matter and open a backdoor to residence in any Schengen country.
So you have to set a limit and it's simply based on the Schengen agreement definition of short stays. Everything under 90 days is a Schengen (now EU) matter, everything above that is a national matter.
In actual fact, the rule isn't actively enforced and there is basically zero risk of any consequences. Its purpose is not to police family trips by students, it's to provide some legal cover to remove people who have a permit from one Schengen country, live full-time in another one (often working illegally) or come to the attention of the authorities in another way, especially if they are deemed “undesirable” (rough sleeping, petty criminality, etc.)
What does happen in those cases is that you are ordered to go back to the country where you do have a residence permit or, rarely, end up being removed by the local police to that country (e.g. physically escorted to a train or handed over to the authorities in your country of residence). Hungarian authorities have no way to invalidate your residence permit or ban you. The only (very theoretical) question is whether the German authorities would then act on any report that you overstayed in Hungary but it's hard to see a basis for that.

I am also thinking this way, but in theory it is not logical, and in practice I think it is just a rule which is not reasonable anymore, at least for cases like this... It was my sister's birthday around 5-6 months ago and because I come to surprise her, I need to leave early and can come back again for the time I was here is "collected" again...

"Hungarian authorities have no way to invalidate your residence permit or ban you" Could Hungarian authorities place a notice in SIS about the person, effectively banning the person from the Schengen area?

@Dr.Snoopy In the logic of the system, the residence permit takes precedence. It makes sense because otherwise, it would effectively give union law (and Hungary) control over something that it is still a national matter (namely residence). The Schengen agreement and everything that stems from it is only supposed to deal with short stays.

In practice, the Schengen Borders Code explicitly provides that countries should grant a residence permit holder the possibility to transit to their country of residence even if there is an alert about them. It's only if there is a national alert that the country is allowed to refuse entry to that specific country. In other words, not only is Hungary not allowed to interfere with German residence permit but it's not even supposed to impact the way other Schengen countries treat that permit.

Conversely, the SIS regulation provides that before entering an alert against a residence permit holder, a country should consult with the country that granted them a permit and is not allowed to enter that alert if the permit is not withdrawn. So it always boils down to: Would German authorities rescind a permit because of some hard-to-verify tip that someone seems to have spent 95 days in another Schengen country?

It's probably worth adding to this answer that Hungarian authorities have no easy way to establish that a residence permit holder situated similarly to D.H.K. has overstayed, since even if such a person had been checked every time at the internal border there's likely no record of the crossings.  They don't even have much basis to form a suspicion of an overstay.

My question was about consequences, you are arguing only about the residence permit, but if overstaying, there can definitely be consequences in another country (Hungary in this case), since national law applies, the person could get fined or jailed, or banned from Hungary, all without involving SIS or Germany.

@Dr.Snoopy Is that a comment for me or for phoog? I am not sure what you think you asked or what you are trying to say now but your comment was in fact exclusively about being banned from the whole Schengen area and the SIS so I explained how that works. If you want to consider additional scenarios, I can try to provide more details but please remain respectful.

Now, under the Returns directive and established precedent, jail is definitely out of the question for an overstay (even a solidly established long overstay for someone who does not have a residence permit). This is just not how this works. A fine or national alert to refuse entry in Hungary in the future are (theoretically) possible, I already alluded to the latter in my comment about the Schengen Borders Code. They are still exceedingly unlikely given the specifics of this question.

Actually the Returns directive allows for detention, even in Jail, for the purpose of removal (Chapter IV), and there is an exception if criminal law sanctions are involved (Article 2), so it would not be something I would risk in Hungary, given current Hungarian Government's views on immigration. You would have to find a specialist in Hungarian national law about that.

@Dr.Snoopy “for the purpose of removal“ are the operative words here and if you are familiar with the Returns directive you can see how it would not apply here, cf. 15(1) and the fact we are talking about someone who would have at most spent a couple of extra days and is ready to return to Germany. Prison is mentioned as an exception in article 16 and case law has found countries in breach of the directive for using it. You most definitely cannot be sentenced to jail for an overstay as your previous comment implied.

Not that this has anything to do with this Q&A or your earlier comment, at this point I have the feeling you are making stuff up as you go…

I am just pointing out possible consequences for an overstay. It does have a lot to do with the question, as it asks directly: "Would I get banned or penalty for this incase it would become a deal?" And Hungary is not the place I would test for consequences, they are already in breach of EU Law.

@Dr.Snoopy You said so many contradictory things that it's hard to know what your point is. The actual consequence for an overstay, as detailed in my answer, could be a forced return to Germany, no Schengen-wide ban and no way to invalidate the residence permit. But even that risk is very remote because there is no way to notice or establish an overstay of that nature.

Now, you are correct that there are many illegal police practices all over Europe (not only in Hungary). Depending on the OP's appearance this could be a valid concern but then why ask about the niceties of the SIS? If the police wants to be hostile, it doesn't really matter whether you technically stayed 89 or 91 days, which, again, is something that the authorities have no way to prove and are not actively enforcing.
